# Connection refused! Is selenium server started

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, selenium, sails.js

I have inherited a project in work with no documentation. It is a sails.js application. 
There is a small set of unit tests and an end-to-end test.

When I try and run the end-to-end test using grunt. I get:

```
$ grunt e2e
Running "nightwatch" task
started - PID:  5440
>> Executing "default" tests (standalone)

[Index] Test Suite
==================

Running:  Should clean the collection

removing 0 places
>> Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
```

I don't know what I could be  missing. This has me stuck for over a week.

**The project has a *selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar* in grunt-nightwatch. So I take the PID is the selenium server starting. If I start the jar first(outside of grunt) I get**

```
$ grunt e2e
org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
18:38:46.189 WARN - Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or     some other service is.
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:491)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:95)
>> Could not start Selenium.
```

Here is the **nightwatch.json**

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests/e2e"],
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }  
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Huge thanks for any help!

p.s. Am on a windows 7 box

Comment: Do you started the Selenium? What address your Selenium running? Please, explain more detail in your question.

Comment: Hi @AntônioCarlos I have updated the question but am not sure what other info to add.

Comment: Look that "Selenium is already running on port 4444". Then, configure your test to running in https://localhost:4444. 

Do you use Jasmine?

Comment: I see chrome in the nightwatch.json.. but I don't know what this means

Comment: Do you can provide more detail of your nightwatch.json and Test Suite?

Comment: The Selenium WebDrive running in host 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

Comment: @AntônioCarlos I really really appreciate your help :) 
I pasted everything from the nightwatch file

Comment: I assume selenium is starting because of the process ID 5440 but then the script just died with "Connection refused! Is selenium server started?"

Comment: Where will I find the "Test Suite" info?

Comment: Hi @codemeasandwich, did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

```
 "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
```

You need to specify your chrome driver location within this line of the nightwatch.json file

For example, i use:

```
"webdriver.chrome.driver" : "~/bin/chromedriver",
```

Also are you starting selenium to use the chrome driver? If not when you boot selenium, append:
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/[username]/bin/chromedriver

So when you start selenium server, it should look like terminal cmd: 
java -jar [SeleniumServerName] -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/[username]/bin/chromedriver

Remember to CD into the seleniumserver folder first and to change around file/folder path structure based on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks so much for including the nightwatch.json file.

I think Jordan is pointing at part of the problem. Out-of-the-box, I haven't been able to get Nightwatch to run on Chrome. My .json file had Firefox everywhere yours says Chrome. I had to download Firefox and it worked without actually setting the drivers Jordan mentioned.

My next problem was the server.

I set the selenium object `start_process` is set to true; nightwatch will then automatically start the server when you run the tests with grunt. You'll also need to set the `server_path` to `some/directory/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar`.

Regardless of whether this solves your immediate problem, it will probably save you time in the future by not having to start the server *then* run the tests.

Comment: I also have this set to true but I get the same error.

Comment: Try restarting your computer. You may already have another selenium task running somewhere taking up port 4444.

Answer (score 3):

just in case anyone else struggles likewise.

I had this issue the last couple of days. The problem was in my case, the chromedriver version was incompatible with the chrome version. I could not tell from the nightwatch output, but added a log output which told me.

**What I saw initially**

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  12835
...
{ Error: Unhandled "error" event. ([object Object])
    at ClientManager.emit (events.js:185:19)
    at Nightwatch.<anonymous> (/home/n23430/dev/Ps.Web/WebTest/ps-web-test/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/clientmanager.js:67:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Nightwatch.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at HttpRequest.<anonymous> (/home/n23430/dev/Ps.Web/WebTest/ps-web-test/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js:501:10)
    at emitThree (events.js:135:13)
    at HttpRequest.emit (events.js:216:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/n23430/dev/Ps.Web/WebTest/ps-web-test/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/http/request.js:168:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
  context: 
   { message: 'Connection refused! Is selenium server started?\n',
     data: { value: [Object], status: 33 } } }
```

*How I spotted the issue*
In the traceback above, there's a reference to line 501 in /node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js. I added a console.log statement there, printing out the 'data' from here, which read this (from start):

```
{
  "value": {
    "stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-79-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)...
```

**Conclusion**
chromedriver version 2.33 needs chrome version >= 60.
Updating chrome resolved my issue.

Kind regards, 
Aril

Answer (score 1):

My issue came because in my /etc/hosts file I had 127.0.0.1 not pointed to localhost.  I fixed that and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while running the selenium server for the first time.

If the selenium console http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/ is also not starting the session, it is likely that the webdriver is not placed or not in PATH. 
If you are using chrome browser, try downloading the chromedriver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ or run `npm install chromedriver`.

If you have downloaded the driver executable separately, don't forget to add it in PATH.